# Pine script Variable to keep a certain ATR level in memory

Tags: variables, pine-script

I created Buy and Sell signals according to RSI levels. No issue with that. However, when I get the BUY or SELL signal, I'd like my code to memorize that candle's ATR level and give me a stop loss signal  when that ATR level is reached.

Is there any way that I can do it?

Many thanks for your support

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var` keyword to store any value.

For example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © protradingart

//@version=5
indicator("keep a certain ATR level", overlay=true)

rsi =  ta.rsi(close, 14)

longCondition = ta.crossover(rsi, 50)
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(rsi, 50)

atr = ta.atr(14)

var slAtr = 0.0

if longCondition
    slAtr := atr

if shortCondition
    slAtr := atr
    
plot(slAtr)
```

Comment: you are the best :) I appreciate your fast  response. Thanks a lot

Comment: @OvguSayan If answer is useful you should accept it, That's why anyone help here.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for not doing that. Did not know I should have done that. I could not see any accept button on this page. Can you please shotyl tell me how I can accept this answer?